# Create Azure DevTest Lab VM from Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: azure, build, azure-devops, azure-devtest-labs

I want to create an Azure DevTest labs VM as part of a build process in Visual Studio Team Services. However when I run a build I get the following error:

```
******************************************************************************
Starting task: Create Azure DevTest Labs VM
******************************************************************************
Executing the powershell script: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.102.0\tasks\AzureDevTestLabsCreateVM\1.0.7\New-AzureDtlVM.ps1
Looking for Azure PowerShell module at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ServiceManagement\Azure\Azure.psd1
AzurePSCmdletsVersion= 1.3.2
Get-ServiceEndpoint -Name ***** -Context Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Agent.Worker.Common.TaskContext
tenantId= ********
azureSubscriptionId= *****
azureSubscriptionName= *****
Add-AzureRMAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant ******** -Credential System.Management.Automation.PSCredential
Select-AzureRMSubscription -SubscriptionId ***** -tenantId ********
Starting Azure DevTest Labs Create VM Task
Task called with the following parameters:
  ConnectedServiceName  = *****
  LabId = *****
  TemplateName = C:\a\1\s\MVC app\azure-rm-template
  TemplateParameters = -newVMName 'builder' -userName 'admin' -password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String ***** -AsPlainText -Force)
  OutputResourceId = labVMId
Validating input parameters
Fetching lab *****
Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Entities.ErrorResponses.ErrorResponseMessageException: MissingSubscription : The request did not have a provided subscription. All requests must have an associated subscription Id.
at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.RestClients.ResourceManagerRestClientBase.<SendRequestAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.RestClients.ResourceManagerRestClientBase.<SendRequestAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.RestClients.ResourceManagerRestClientBase.<SendRequestAsync>d__1b`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.GetAzureResourceCmdlet.<GetResource>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.GetAzureResourceCmdlet.<GetResources>d__c.MoveNext()
```

I have connected VSTS to Azure using a service principal and I am using the DevTest labs tasks provided by Microsoft (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuredevtestlabs.tasks).

It's very confusing because the error claims "MissingSubscription" but the logs for that very task contain all of my subscription information?!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be caused by the "Lab Name" you entered in "Azure DevTest Labs Create VM" task is incorrect. Make sure you have created the DevTest Lab in Azure Portal, and then in the "Azure DevTest Labs Create VM" task, you should see it from the drop-down list of "Lab Name', choose it from there.
[image]

If the Lab Name is correct, you should see the "LabID" in the log the same as following format:

```
LabId = /subscriptions/subscriptionID/resourceGroups/resourcegroupname/providers/Microsoft.DevTestLab/labs/LabName
```